# Is it possible to select the logged in email account in MFMailcomposeViewController swift?

Tags: swift, email, mfmailcomposer

My question may be a mere foolishness. MFmailComposeViewController automatically selects the logged in email account in the device as the sender e-mail.  I just want to know whether it is possible to select the email account (if there are multiple accounts logged in (yahoo, google, iCloud etc.))? I am using a simple mailComposer, and there is no complex codes. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Check this out]When you use MFmailComposeViewController it automatically sets up the email account. Don't worry, it won't select the wrong account.

If you tap it gives you a choice

Comment: I know, it won't select the wrong account. But, is it possible to make a selection?

Comment: All the user has to do anyway is tap the email address and it will display all the email addresses

Comment: A user sees the most commonly used one but can change it with one tap. It's an easy, great system

Comment: How? I didn't understand the last one. How all email addresses will be displayed?

Comment: If you have set it up properly it should display whatever address you set in the 'To' field and the most common email address in the 'From' field. If a user has several email addresses, when tapped it shows the other options

Comment: Have a look at my post

Comment: It really works. It was just a confusion in setting up the accounts in my device. Thank You.

Comment: Great. Good luck with your app! @MohammedJanish